# ¿Qué especie de pájaro es un "siu"? ¿De dónde viene su nombre?

Tags: etimología, animales, chile

El DLE solo dice:

> [**siu**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Y30E4kr)
>
> 1. m. Pájaro americano muy semejante al jilguero.

¿Qué tipo de pájaro es exactamente, y cuál es la etimología de su nombre?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En su primera entrada en el DLE (1917) dice:

> **SIU.** m. *Amer.* Entre los indios [araucanos](https://dle.rae.es/?id=3PbdEzZ|3Pbx76V), **jilguero**.

Dado esto, es probable que la palabra venga del mapuche.

Las entradas siguientes (1925 - 1989) afirman que se usa en Chile. Dado que [las únicas especies de fringílidos ("jilgueros") que viven en Chile](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Aves_de_Chile#Fringillidae_(Jilgueros)) son los "siskins", es probable que se refiera a [una de] las cinco especies que hay.

Answer (score 1):

**Siú** corresponde a la especie *Spinus Barbatus* (jilguero "cabeza negra" o "siskin"). Habita en Argentina y Chile; en claros, parques y pueblos y se desplaza en numerosas bandadas.

Según el naturalista francés C. S. Sonnini (1751-1812), el nombre "siú" (probablemente onomatopéyico) de estas aves proviene del mapudungún (la lengua mapuche) y significa "jilguero".

[image: Jilguero golinegro (Spinus Barbatus)]